# Mongoose - update document field based on a date

Tags: node.js, mongoose

In my current project I have a schema of bids. The bid schema looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const timestamps = require('mongoose-timestamps');

const BidSchema = new Schema({
  bidder: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Buyer'
  },
  box: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Box'
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Pending', 'Approved', 'Disapproved']
  },
  bidPrice: Number,
  bidTerms: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Cash', '30 Days', '60 Days', '90 Days', '120 Days']
  },
  bidTimeout: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  isAnonymous: Boolean,
});

BidSchema.plugin(timestamps);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Bid', BidSchema);
```

Now, as you can see, I have a field `bidTimeout` of type date that represents time out of the bid. Now, in this schema I also have an enum field called status which represents the status of the bid(Approved, Disapproved, Pending). The initial status of the bid when it is created is pending.
Now, in my server, I want to perform some logic on the bids. I want that for 
every bid that its bidTimeout has passed, I want the status of this bid to be 'Disapproved'.

I thought about performing a cron job or another task scheduler but I wondered if there is a better, more effective way of achieving this.

Comment: yes, the cronjob is the better way to automatically update the result when bidding timeout. But do you have any special requirement other than this?

Answer (score 0):

Cronjobs are not the best way to go about this as the implementation won't scale very well.

If you do need to update the status in real time for some reason, a scheduler is a better way to implement that.

But a more simple approach would be to not go real time. Whenever any bid is loaded from the database, check if it is expired and in Pending state. If it is then change state to Disapproved and save the object.